# RDS for SQL Server to EC2 Migration

Tags: amazon-ec2, server, migration, amazon-rds

Does anyone know how we can migrate SQL Server from RDS to EC2? We have some privilege problem using RDS, and decided to move to EC2 for more administration freedom.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create SQL Server on an EC2
2. Backup the RDS SQL Server
3. Restore the RDS backup to the EC2 SQL Server

Microsoft instruction for the last 2 steps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/quickstart-backup-restore-database?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. One more thing, can we use third party tools to migrate and maybe how about if we want to use replication on the current rds to ec2?